# Change date time to specific format

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

I've a Date Time string as 27th October 2020 07:30 PM.
And I want it in format yyyy-mm-dd 07:30 PM.

Is there a way to convert in flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you import the intl package from pub.dev you can format the date any way you like.

https://pub.dev/packages/intl

You can see here in the docs where all the available premade datetime formatting constructors are. https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html

```
 ICU Name                   Skeleton
 --------                   --------
 DAY                          d
 ABBR_WEEKDAY                 E
 WEEKDAY                      EEEE
 ABBR_STANDALONE_MONTH        LLL
 STANDALONE_MONTH             LLLL
 NUM_MONTH                    M
 NUM_MONTH_DAY                Md
 NUM_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY        MEd
 ABBR_MONTH                   MMM
 ABBR_MONTH_DAY               MMMd
 ABBR_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY       MMMEd
 MONTH                        MMMM
 MONTH_DAY                    MMMMd
 MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY            MMMMEEEEd
 ABBR_QUARTER                 QQQ
 QUARTER                      QQQQ
 YEAR                         y
 YEAR_NUM_MONTH               yM
 YEAR_NUM_MONTH_DAY           yMd
 YEAR_NUM_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY   yMEd
 YEAR_ABBR_MONTH              yMMM
 YEAR_ABBR_MONTH_DAY          yMMMd
 YEAR_ABBR_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY  yMMMEd
 YEAR_MONTH                   yMMMM
 YEAR_MONTH_DAY               yMMMMd
 YEAR_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY       yMMMMEEEEd
 YEAR_ABBR_QUARTER            yQQQ
 YEAR_QUARTER                 yQQQQ
 HOUR24                       H
 HOUR24_MINUTE                Hm
 HOUR24_MINUTE_SECOND         Hms
 HOUR                         j
 HOUR_MINUTE                  jm
 HOUR_MINUTE_SECOND           jms
 HOUR_MINUTE_GENERIC_TZ       jmv
 HOUR_MINUTE_TZ               jmz
 HOUR_GENERIC_TZ              jv
 HOUR_TZ                      jz
 MINUTE                       m
 MINUTE_SECOND                ms
 SECOND                       s
```

You can also make your own formatting however you like. For example, I have my formatting like so:

```
DateFormat.yMMMd().format(transactions[index].date),
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a DateTime type or a String type ?

```
DateTime date = DateTime.now();
print(date.toString())
```

Cause I get what you want with that code.

console :

```
2020-10-23 15:36:11.846645
```